# Can you concatenate a variable amount of text in SQL?

Tags: sql, concatenation

I am working with SQL.  At my company, we have a table that shows the text that a technician has written while on a service call.  However, when the text is saved in a table, IT separates it out by line.  In other words, one call text could contain five or more records.  I would like to write a query that will show the call number one time and the text that goes with it in one record.  The problem is that the call text can be anywhere from 5 to 25 lines / records.  Each record has the same call number.  Is there a way in SQL to concatenate all the lines of text for one call?

Comment: Are you working on MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using SQL server, you can use the following query:

```
select call_number,
  stuff((SELECT distinct ' ' + text_column
           FROM Table_Name T2
           where T2.call_number = T1.call_number
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
from Table_Name T1
group by call_number
```

Comment: I use this all the time to concatenate text in multiple rows. One thing to keep in mind is that you may need to identify the TYPE if there are invalid XML characters. For example `( SELECT FROM FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', N'nvarchar(max)')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(description, '. ') FROM calls WHERE number = '123456';
```